# Double ajax post won't work in ExpressionEngine 3.x with Email module

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, expressionengine

I'm working on an ExpressionEngine 3.5.10 website which uses the native [Email module](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email/index.html) and [contact form](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email/contact_form.html).

I'm also using the jQuery [validate.js](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin, version 1.15.0.

The form is submitted with ajax and validated by the validate.js plugin:

```
$("#contactUsForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "firstName": "required", 
            "lastName": "required",     
            "email": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            "comments": "required"
        },
        messages: {
            "firstName": "Please enter your first name",  
            "lastName": "Please enter your last name",  
            "email": {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
            },
            "comments": "Please enter a message"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
           var dataString = $( "form" ).serialize();

           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $("#contactUsForm").attr('action'),
                data: dataString,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#contactFormContainer').html('');
                    $('#contactFormContainer').append('<h3>Thanks, we\'ve received your message and will be in touch shortly!</h3>');
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    $('#contactFormContainer').html('');
                    $('#contactFormContainer').append('<h3>Sorry, an error has occured. Please contact us using the details given below.</h3>');
                }
           });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This all works and the form is posted to the correct URL - defined in `$("#contactUsForm").attr('action')`

However, *after* this post is made, I need to make a second post, to a different URL.

So I added the following code in my `submitHandler`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/site/test",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
         console.log('error!');
    }
    });
```

When I do this, the post request is made to `/site/test` but ExpressionEngine returns the following error message:

> You are only allowed to submit email forms every 20 seconds

I understand this is an ExpressionEngine specific error. But, is there any way around this, or a different way to get it to do the post request to the separate URL?